# Unsure of what this http response is (Phone Application Data Scraping)

Tags: python, web-scraping, https, python-requests, response

I am trying to scrape messages off of this phone application (similar to a messaging application) and I was using burp suite to obtain https request information and all the information returned is in funky letters. I'm not sure if this affects it, but this app is Korean. [Picture of Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IyEd.png)

Not sure if this is needed but additional information below.

Content-Type: application/json

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

Accept-Language: en-US;q=1, ko-US;q=0.9

The end results is that I want to receive the information from the api in english or korean. I can provide the api get request python code if needed.

Response:

```
xœíWmoÛ6þ+?×6ïÌÇ4,E‡.Ý—¢0(òèhU$Á–²AþûHŠvœ-ÙK´Ð/ïxw¼;ñžÇº9ÜõOx3;>šQE”¥ÎsePY�ÐŽ–XA)/‚ä³WG³Ú_Üô˜< ‰›®»ÚFév†qÂh^7v;¼¾´Ã"-<6C}•\Ú±i¢Ï~·öŸS C•b†’VMç>½Áv<¯·CÜý0«ÛëzÀ´wÝMÏ~l×éiG_w9©+»ž,jYãºv°nHËP7“WcÎ>¦Í
Úã7¹-™‘,Ù´ö
T0<5f_i.hJûvïw|´¯ Úí\´wQŸû¦ó¸ðñä‡íèzlS;rÌj¬ª/ló)‹WöóYÛÃ9¶ëáòí§ƒã/KgÅàéœ|® YS<<¯e^Ë);‘Öñ7®uÖkR"•PIbY`%nŽ:i‹:I*Š”H%T9»ž$š:ù¤¶(5i‹ºÄ*ÁrŽdós’'©ì•­”‘)!)¦*K™¥S3Rï7¸ÅáöÍÍ©M—=%pööbuòþääü‡Õ/ïOVo>{Þ|¼ÍjzËƒ‹±«­ÛÔþØØuJ ê~Çêµu—ùÂ,m_/¯aY<ÓeY^ávïåRb$WžJhU�ë*é°\¦¤£”+â8µR{c*/L—Üië••†VVI*PN”£S¢M¬!në4 Òè Ð‚õÚ{"@á%·Œ¬rþƒÝ¤[uj›¦êö¾¢Ó‹<ÿ„Ò9‘sàGŽ   =&»ºÌ;¶þÐ^ÏAf{8æfwÎðtÄ»Åæý4{öCôñ°É÷ˆNÐä{W¦0OÄ.«1ØuŽw»³)Ð²¥lÇ~ˆh·}ˆD§Ød0ÚÆÒ
Üý¡Á.äÞöCÝµø¹híê˜ÅM¹!dg6‡´þWÜÔagw‡ˆXa×DSJ%…dŒš|¬mÛnlVº=ž«õYÂÂ=x^C¿=^.+;ï7]‚Â¹kíf>.\·ìÃ*å~²^Õ«nGv’ƒŽ
®¤YüÖ¯ó«Yoº±?›:ÛQÙ6µ3(ý¼{µë7û` ‰øÆ$ Ä˜îÁâ`ë¸‡ûRA‚†Ë½ö;  ¼d˜Þþs’�0­�
¥ŠKRI©€`¥‘b|O–­)‡”{ëwÜU<ÄµñRg‚¯"1„È%Ú+M­qF
æ•&¼‚àÍÿŸbŸ“Ø‹$xÇ¦Fàìk@¤ãB`¤&êq`C\*eä—‘€øÖ$�ùð_‡$+¸'8Ô~'—LðÜ$ ]ˆKÅ(xÏP  ª•Šä+Cµ�”Q…TGôg•¥Á�@àà±ÜB0¡rî"g ªFbð\2tVþ€9åG@¨ò¯H€Ê#È$Àø£$ð0âS$�O’@üüø›|¿„
(½Tšò¡šóuH@ìI€SFô£$ Ÿ iÔÒ¹³‹Í˜1÷OõÐtJs‘àîm¹ö@
```

Comment: What is the URL and how do you make the request?

Comment: Because it is httpS request, all data are encrypted. Try to use https://www.charlesproxy.com/ and also you will need to install SSL certificate on your mobile phone.

Comment: The url is https://ba-api.dear-u.co @AndrejKesely

Comment: Even using charlesproxy, the response is the same bunch of encrypted text. I've enabled SSL proxying and everything. Not sure what I need to do here past this point. [charlesproxy results](https://i.imgur.com/NyTTEtj.png) @MeT

Comment: @mdssi what mobile phone do you use? Android?

Comment: @MeT iOS, iPhone

Comment: @mdssi Did you install the certificate on your iphone from charlies?

Comment: @MeT Yes. It returned the same results as the other listener.